# Can I delete padding in a Buefy-Bulma layout component?

Tags: css, vue.js, bulma, buefy

I am building a simple to-do list on Vue.js using Buefy interface component library which uses the design framework Bulma...

The app is designed to be only a single page full-width so I used the Hero layout component of bulma for that: https://bulma.io/documentation/layout/hero/

App.vue:

```js
<div id="app">

      <!-- Hero component de Buefy .start -->
      <section class="hero is-warning is-fullheight">

           <div class="title">
            <h2 v-if="after === ''">{{before}}</h2>
           <div class="container column is-one-third is-three-quarters-mobile" >
            <b-field class="name-input">
              <b-input v-model="after" placeholder="ejemplo: 'lista de la compra miercoles'">
              </b-input>
            </b-field>
            <b-button id="create-todo-btn" type="is-primary">Crear Lista</b-button>
            <b-button id="delete-todo-btn" type="is-danger" disabled>Borrar Lista</b-button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Container del Centro .start-->
        <div class="hero-body">
          <div class="container wrapper-todo">
            <h1 class="title" v-if="after !== ''">{{after}}</h1>
            <TodoItem></TodoItem>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Container del Centro .end -->

          <!--Footer .start-->
         <div class="hero-foot">
            <TodoListFooter></TodoListFooter>
          </div>
        <!-- Footer .end -->

      </section>
      <!-- Hero component de Buefy .end -->

  </div>
```

The problem is there is way too much padding and margin between `<div class="title">` and `<div class="hero-body">` I´d like to know if its possible to delete this padding (or at least some of it) in the `.hero-body` class.

I have looked at documentation and haven´t seen anything. I have also try with my own css classes and it doesn´t seem to override the default styles and definetely it doesn´t delete any padding.

Also tried the `"is-paddingless"` custom class and it doesn´t work either.

Comment: Show it on the browser and then view the elements and then modify the css or look directly at the source code...i used this for modified element-ui style.

Comment: The paddings and marign are useing rem units so they are based on the root font size. The sizes are defined by the author and can be modified using custom class and add that class to hero-body e.g `hero-body custom-padding` and add the padding you want

Comment: @Aslam I´ve tried that and it looks it doesn´t work.

Comment: @onlycau The weird thing is I have tried that and most of the padding doesn´t go away still, i can´t believe it. I think I will try it with single components and ditch the Hero away

Comment: can you check your developer tools and see if there is another property overwriting it?